# Tuple stored as an Array in Elasticsearch with Pig and EsStorage plugin

Tags: apache-pig

I am having an issue with the format [EsStorage](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop) store tuples into Elasticsearch.

Let's take a concrete example:

```
X: {id: chararray,score: long,answers: {(id: chararray,score: long)}}
(4,385,{(7,287),(7263,48)})
```

I am using the following ESStorage configuration:

```
DEFINE EsStorage org.elasticsearch.hadoop.pig.EsStorage (
              'es.http.timeout= 5m',
              'es.index.auto.create = true',
              'es.mapping.pig.tuple.use.field.names = true',
              'es.nodes = $es_nodes',
              'es.mapping.id = id'
           );
```

And I store my tuples like this:

```
STORE X INTO '$es_index_name/$es_index_type' USING EsStorage;
```

The result is the following:

```
     {
        "_index": "stackoverflow_test3",
        "_type": "post",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "id": "4",
           "score": 385,
           "answers": [
              [
                 {
                    "id": "7",
                    "score": 287
                 }
              ],
              [
                 {
                    "id": "7263",
                    "score": 48
                 }
              ]
          }
    }
```

I'am expecting to have something like this:

```
     {
        "_index": "stackoverflow_test3",
        "_type": "post",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "id": "4",
           "score": 385,
           "answers": [
                 {
                    "id": "7",
                    "score": 287
                 },
                 {
                    "id": "7263",
                    "score": 48
                 }
             ]
          }
    }
```

Do you know how could I achieve this ?

Thank you

Comment: Good luck dude ;-)